# How to take absolute value in docplex without calling the built-in function?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, absolute-value, binary-operations, quadratic-programming

I have the Constraint:
$$
| \sum x_{i} - n/2 | \leq 0 
$$

where each $x_{i}$ is a binary variable, and $n$ is the total number of variables.

in docplex, I encode this as:

`mod.add_constraint(mod.abs(sum([i for i in var]) - n//2) <= 0)`

When I do so, docplex creates an SOS (special ordered set). These sets are are not handled by the secondary method I am using, which causes an error.

As I cannot alter the secondary function, I have been trying to find a way to compute absolute value without calling `mod.abs()`, `mod.max()` (which causes a similar problem) or squaring terms. One simple way to do so (logically) is:

```
P = sum([i for i in var] - n//2)
if -P >= P:
    P = -P
```

Doing this directly causes docplex to throw "no linear constraint in logical test" error, and Report "Cannot convert linear constraint to a boolean value: (-x0-x1-x2... + n) >= (x0 + x1 + x2...-n)".

All I really want here, is for the value of P to always be positive. Is there a more simple way (perhaps through an indicator, an if-else constraint, or big M) that I can encode this?

Comment: Can't you just write $\sum x_i = n/2$?

Comment: Yes, except the secondary method I alluded to converts constraints to penalties, which means that term will become a square of sums, causing exponential blow of terms. This was the original reason for the shift to absolute value

Comment: Please format your math with MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Surely the blow-up of terms can be at most quadratic, not exponential :)

Comment: "Docplex" : Can you give at least of reference about this dinosaur-named software  ?

Comment: Please answer my modest request. I would like you give a *thorough* reference about this software.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that in general, there is a better way to write $\left|\sum_i x_i - \frac n2\right| \le 0$ than $\sum_i x_i = \frac n2$: if there were, wouldn't we use it on all equality constraints all the time?

But to answer the question more generally, if we want to encode a constraint of the form $|A| \le B$ without using absolute value, one natural option is the pair of constraints $$\begin{cases}\phantom{-}A \le B, \\ -A \le B. \end{cases}$$ This will not work with a lower bound on the absolute value, because $|A| \ge B$ is not a convex constraint.